# Firefox SDK context menu. Add item that reacts according to type of selection or node clicked

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build a Firefox plug-in that adds to FF context menu a item that reacts defferently according to what the user has right clicked on:

- First behaviour = the user selects some text and right-clicks on it
- Second behaviour = the user right-clicks on and image
- Third behaviour = the user right-clicks on a link

As soon as the user right-clicks an element the plugin launches an external EXE with as parameter a string with the selected text of with the link (link or link to image).

**Up to now I managed to work it out by my self** **BUT** the issue I'm having is that now I have two separate working plug-ins. I don't know how to tell javascript that "if you detected a selected text do this", "if you detected a image or a link do that". I mean, **I don't know how to put the two snippets together!**

**Plug-in #1: TEXT SELECTION:**

```
var {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
var contextMenu = require('sdk/context-menu');
var selection = require('sdk/selection');


var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "send selected text to...",
    context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function() {' +
                        'var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                        'self.postMessage(text);' +
                        '});',
    onMessage: function(args) {
        var args = [selection.text];                       
        var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
        file.initWithPath("c:\\cmdline.exe");

        var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
        process.init(file);

        process.run(false, args, args.length);
    }                       
});
```

**Plug-in #2: LINK and IMAGE:**

```
var {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");

cm.Item({
    label: "send link/image to...",
    context: cm.SelectorContext("a[href], img"),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 '  self.postMessage(node.src);' +
                 '});',
    onMessage: function(imgsrc) {
        var args = [imgsrc];                       
        var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
        file.initWithPath("c:\\cmdline.exe");

        var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
        process.init(file);

        process.run(false, args, args.length);
    }
```

**cmdline.EXE** is a simple EXE that opens a MsgBox that prompt its commad line parameter.

As you may notice, the context menu label changes according to the object right-clicked. I don't know how to do it programmatically.

P.S. don't know why, but the console keeps returing "Line 0: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'", but the plug in still works

Comment: Instead of the command the exe for a simple MsgBox you can use js-ctypes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes#Calling_Windows_routines

Comment: Check `node.nodeType` see here for all the types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: The two snippets work correctly, I'm simply asking how to put them together. The first uses SelectionContext, the second uses SelectorContext. How these may conciliate?

Comment: make a function called function doMyMessage(imgSrc, args), then use both SelectionContext and SelectorContext but pass different args to your doMyMessage function